# Make an SKPhysicsBody dynamic with action

Tags: swift, dynamic, timer, skaction

Is there a way I can use an SKAction to make an SKPhysicsBody change its 'dynamic' property from false to true, or vise versa? My intention is to create a sequence of two actions, the first being SKAction.waitForDuration(1.5), and the second one setting the SKPhysicsBody's dynamic property to true

Comment: Why do you want to change the `dynamic` property at run-time?

Comment: I want the object to interact with other objects at some times but not others

Comment: You should set/un-set the appropriate `contactTestBitMask` bits instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't touched Swift, but in Objective-C you'd call `runAction: completion:` with your wait action and a block of custom code.

```
[someNode runAction:myAction completion:^{
            //do my code in here
            [someNode setSomeProperty: someValue];
        }];
```